# azure devops pipeline yml variable overridden by build variable, default if not

Tags: azure, yaml, devops, pipeline

I struggled to find the answer to this so posting a question as I don't think it is obvious.

I want to be able to use a variable in my yml defined build in azure devops/visualstudio.com. If I create the variable on the build pipeline in the UI then I want it to use that value, otherwise I want the build to continue using a default value set in the yml.

Use ...

```
variables:
  usefulVariable: $[ coalesce( variables.uiVariable, 'defaultValue' ) ]
```

At runtime (ie when it's building) the $[] function will be evaluated ... if the build has the uiVariable defined in the UI then it will use that value ... otherwise it will be set to 'defaultValue'.

I found this useful for converting a load of yml files to allow the option to override a variable but not break the existing builds if the value was not overridden.

In the documentation I can only find examples of calling functions inside ${{..}} ... which are only evaluated when the yml is submitted to ADO/VS as a build definition (compile time).